# Eclipse java builds contains both .java and .class files

Tags: java, eclipse

When i build my java projects in eclipse for some reason it puts both class and java files inside the build
Which makes it double the size
How to turn this off?

Edit: Export sources is NOT checked (would have been a real DOH moment!)
When building blackberry projects there is no such option

Edit2: It's happening in 2 different eclipse environments so as far as i can figure it must be a global "setting" somewhere

Comment: how are you building it?

Comment: You able to .java file elsewhere other than build directory where .class files also resides?

Comment: Eugene: i right click on the project and choose export -> war file
however it also happens when i build blackberry projects using their own signature tool

RP: im not sure i understand what you mean?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, but my colleague is fine, he is using older version of Eclipse.
Now, I have to open the war file and delete java source files with 7zip or other zip manager.

Answer (score 1):

When you export it as a WAR file there is a check option to select if you want to export the sources as well. uncheck it.

Comment: its not checked and it still happens

Answer (score 0):

When exporting to a war file in Eclipse, there is a checkbox saying "Export source file". If checked, it will export the .java files, otherwise not. It is not checked by default.

Comment: its not checked and it still happens